# What does a drools fact check (when) return when one uses the "in" operator

Tags: drools

I have the following rule

```
rule One
 when
    vg1 : Vgdoc(code() in ("IA1003", "IA1004"), colour == "red")
 then
     .. do something with vg1
end
```

when I use the vg1 in the then clause I see that it represents one object but what if both ("IA1003", "IA1004") exists? does drools only send the first one or both? and if it sends both how can I check it.

Is it possible to do something like this to

```
vglist : List() from collect (Vgdok(code() in ("IA1003", "IA1004")))
```

will this list contain both fact if they exists in the memory?

cheers

es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule will hit for each item in working memory that matches.

Simplifying things, let's say that your model looks like this:

```
class Vgdoc {
  public String getCode() { ... }
  public String getColour() { ... }
}
```

And your rule is like what you have, syntax corrected:

```
rule "One"
when
  vg1: Vgdoc( code in ("IA1003", "IA1004"),
              colour == "red" )
then
  Systen.out.println("Rule 1 fired");
end
```

And you have objects in working memory:

```
Vgdoc{ code: "IA1003", colour: "red" } // A
Vgdoc{ code: "IA1004", colour: "red" } // B
Vgdoc{ code: "IA1005", colour: "red" } // C
Vgdoc{ code: "IA1003", colour: "blue" } // D
```

Then your rule will fire twice, once for the item I commented as "A" and once for the item I commented as "B". (Eg. there will be two instances of `Rule 1 fired` printed.) It will not fire for item commented "C" because the code does not match, and it will not fire for item commented "D" because the colour field does not match.

Now, if you want to only fire once and to do something with the *collection* of all Vgdoc matching the condition (color 'red' and code 'IA1003' or 'IA1004'), then yes you'd use a collect. Something like this:

```
rule "IA1003 and IA1004 with red"
when
  vgList: List() from collect( Vgdoc( code in ("IA1003", "IA1004"), colour == "red" ))
then
  System.out.println("Rule fired, match count: " + vgList.size());
  // vgList will contain all items that match the conditions for code and colour
end
```

This version of the rule, with the same inputs from before, will fire exactly once and will print: `Rule fired, match count: 2`.

Which one you choose to use depends on your use case.

Comment: One small comment, when you use a `collect` your rule will fire even if there are not items matching your pattern (it will fire with an empty List). One common pattern when using a collect is to filter out empty Lists: `vgList: List(empty == false) from collect(...)`

Comment: Right. So if you had the rule like I had described, but none of the items in working memory matched, it would print `Rule fired, match count: 0`. As an alternative to `empty == false`, you can also restrict by size -- eg. `List( size >= 2)` will only fire the rule if there are at least 2 Vgdoc instances in working memory that match the conditions and have been collected into the list.